# upload file/image without saving it in local file system in selenum webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

is it possible to upload file/image without saving it in local file system in selenum webdriver  ?
Can we use in memory stream or file/image url in send_keys args ?
I am trying to do this

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "className").send_keys("path 
 of the file")
```

Can we pass in-memory stream or photo url instead ?

Comment: Do expect Yes/No answer or what? Show us your current code and share output/exception trace

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.